How to receive UDP Broadcast in Swift?
Unicast
I can implement unicast:
func receiveUnicast() {
    listener = try? NWListener(using: .udp, on: port)
    listener?.stateUpdateHandler = { state in
        print("listener:stateUpdateHandler", state)
    }
    listener?.newConnectionHandler = { connection in
        print("listener:newConnectionHandler", connection)
        connection.stateUpdateHandler = { state in
            print("connection:stateUpdateHandler", state)
        }
        self.receiveUnicastMessage(connection)
        connection.start(queue: DispatchQueue(label: "Connection"))
        self.connections.append(connection)
    }
    listener?.start(queue: .main)
}

func receiveUnicastMessage(_ connection: NWConnection) {
    connection.receiveMessage { content, contentContext, isComplete, error in
        print("connection:receiveMessage", content?.count ?? 0)
        self.receiveUnicastMessage(connection)
    }
}

Broadcast
However, when, on my game console, I change the broadcast method to broadcast. This code breaks. It will find a connection. It will receive the first message. But then everything is messing up and it will result in many console errors such as:
nw_path_evaluator_create_flow_inner failed NECP_CLIENT_ACTION_ADD_FLOW (null) evaluator parameters: udp, definite, server, attribution: developer, reuse local address, context: Default Network Context (private), proc: 6C2099B1-DBCE-3A78-804D-602E9D490DFA, local address: 0.0.0.0:12203
nw_path_evaluator_create_flow_inner NECP_CLIENT_ACTION_ADD_FLOW A603BF21-071E-42B4-86FA-8F0A416126C7 [17: File exists]
nw_endpoint_flow_setup_channel [C2 192.168.1.4:60485 initial channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, ipv6, dns, uses wifi)] failed to request add nexus flow
nw_endpoint_handler_create_from_protocol_listener [C2 192.168.1.4:60485 failed channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0[802.11], ipv4, ipv6, dns, uses wifi)] nw_endpoint_flow_pre_attach_protocols
nw_connection_create_from_protocol_on_nw_queue [C2] Failed to create connection from listener

In the documentation I found NWConnectionGroup which lead me to NWMulticastGroup. However, it's not multicast, I need broadcast. So I am wondering, is this simply not supported and do I need to look into lower level network code like BSD-sockets or do I need to use NWMulticastGroup also for broadcast?
When I try the code.
do {
    print(localhost, port)
    let multicast = try NWMulticastGroup(for: [.hostPort(host: localhost, port: port)])
    print(multicast)
} catch {
    print(error)
    return
}

I get an error in the console:
POSIXErrorCode(rawValue: 22): Invalid argument

I am completely stuck.

you can't use broadcast with NWListener

Clear answer Paulw11. Not the result I was hoping for but at least I am no longer in doubt. The full answer: "However, not all UDP communication is that straightforward. UDP also supports multicast, broadcast, and other asymmetric designs. Network framework supports UDP multicast using the NWConnectionGroup class, but that support has limits and, specifically, it does not support UDP broadcast. If you need something that’s not supported by Network framework, use BSD Sockets."
